# How to open a document URL in default ios APP using Swft 3?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, openurl

I have a url document url list in a TableViewController` like this one

> https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2004Nov/att-0015/App-Note-UseOfTheFileURLInJDF-031111.doc

and on TableViewCell selection this doc file should open in any default viewer that is not part my app, So I can do achieve this ? Is this possible or any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried using the UIWebView?

Comment: No, I think that will work but I don't think it will open files in default viewer

Comment: Yes, It will open, UIWeb​View is a class to embed web content in your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with [**Quick​Look**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quicklook) Framework should satisfied your requirement.

As mentioned at "[Using the Quick Look Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html)":

> A Quick Look preview controller can display previews for the following
>   items:
>
> - iWork documents
> - **Microsoft Office documents (Office ‘97 and newer)**
> - Rich Text Format (RTF) documents
> - PDF files
> - Images
> - Text files whose uniform type identifier (UTI) conforms to the public.text type
> - Comma-separated value (csv) files

You can find many of articles about working with QuickLook Framework; You might want to check the following one:

[Using Quick Look Framework for Previewing Documents](http://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/).

Also, checking [this repo](https://github.com/TanelTeemusk/QuickLook) (GitHub) might be useful.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks I'll give a try to this

Answer (score 3):

Use `UIWebView` class to open the given URL.

**Method 1:**

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
webView.scalesPageToFit = true
view.addSubview(webView)

let urlS = "https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2004Nov/att-0015/App-Note-UseOfTheFileURLInJDF-031111.doc"
let url = URL(string: urlS)
let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

**Method 2:**

With this method, you'll get nice ToolBar items, which you can customize based on your requirement.

Using UIWebView library for Swift, [SwiftWebView](https://github.com/meismyles/SwiftWebVC):

If you're using `UINavigationController`:

```
let urlS = "https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2004Nov/att-0015/App-Note-UseOfTheFileURLInJDF-031111.doc"
let webVC = SwiftWebVC(urlString: urlS)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(webVC, animated: true)
```

*OR*

If you want to present Modally:

```
let urlS = "https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/uri/2004Nov/att-0015/App-Note-UseOfTheFileURLInJDF-031111.doc"
let webVC = SwiftModalWebVC(urlString: urlS)
self.present(webVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```